# Delphi Rtti Get Property - Why does this results in AV?

Tags: delphi, generics, rtti

I am trying to write a spec utility library.

One of the Specification is a TExpressionSpecification. Basically, it implements the Specification pattern by evaluating an inner TExpression.

One of the TExpression is a TPropertyExpression. It's simply an expression that gets the value of a property by its name with Rtti.

I implemented it the simplest way I could, but really cannot understand why it throws an AV at me.

I stepped throrouly with the debugger. All types are what they are supposed to be. I just dont know why the TRttiProperty.GetValue is wrecking havoc.

Can anybody help?
    unit Spec;

```
interface

uses

Classes;

type

TPropertyExpression<TObjectType, TResultType> = class

private
  FPropertyName: string;
public
  constructor Create(aPropertyName: string); reintroduce;
  function Evaluate(aObject: TObjectType): TResultType;
  property PropertyName: string read FPropertyName write FPropertyName;
end;

procedure TestIt;

implementation

uses

Rtti;

constructor TPropertyExpression<TObjectType, TResultType>.Create(aPropertyName:
    string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  PropertyName := aPropertyName;
end;

function TPropertyExpression<TObjectType, TResultType>.Evaluate(aObject:
    TObjectType): TResultType;
var
  aCtx : TRttiContext;
  aModelType : TRttiType;
  aResultType : TRttiType;
  aProperty : TRttiProperty;
  aValue : TValue;
begin
  aCtx := TRttiContext.Create;
  aModelType := aCtx.GetType(System.TypeInfo(TObjectType));
  aResultType := aCtx.GetType(System.TypeInfo(TResultType));
  aProperty := aModelType.GetProperty(PropertyName);
  aValue := aProperty.GetValue(Addr(aObject));
  Result := aValue.AsType<TResultType>;  
end;

procedure TestIt;
var
  aComponent : TComponent;
  aSpec : TPropertyExpression<TComponent, string>;
begin
  aComponent := TComponent.Create(nil);
  aComponent.Name := 'ABC';
  aSpec := TPropertyExpression<TComponent, string>.Create('Name');
  WriteLn(aSpec.Evaluate(aComponent));
  Readln; 
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetValue` expects the instance pointer (`aObject`) but you are passing it the address of the pointer variable (`@aObject`).

Constrain your `TObjectType` to a class type:

```
type
  TPropertyExpression<TObjectType: class; TResultType> = class...
```

Then, instead of `Addr(aObject)`, pass the instance directly:

```
  aValue := aProperty.GetValue(Pointer(aObject));
```

Comment: There is no need to type cast to `Pointer`, just pass the object pointer as-is: `GetValue(aObject)`.

Comment: Also, keep on mind that records can have properties, too, so you shouldn't use a `class` constraint. Unless you define a separate expression class to handle record instances separately from class instances.

Comment: Without the cast, I get E2010 Incompatible types: 'Pointer' and 'TObjectType'. And while you're right that records can have properties, RTTI for record properties is not supported. So I just assumed it was OK to constrain to class types only.

Comment: I answered a question recently on rtti for properties of records. I think that is supported.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan From my experiments with the code above, `aModelType.GetProperty` always returned nil for a record type. Also, the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Information_for_Structured_Types#Classes.2C_Interfaces.2C_and_Records) says it's not supported (perhaps I misunderstood it).

Comment: I think you right completely, and I have mis-remembered. Thanks, and sorry.

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: Thank you both for your explanations.